# CSS is not working while using shortcode in slider revolution of a custom form with custom plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, web-deployment

I've made a custom form with custom plugin & the issue is css / background color is not showing/working in 'Slider revolution' while using shortcode, it is just showing my form with transparent background but works great in other pages, post.

How can i fix that? (btw i've included css in plugin which works in post/pages)

There's a difference with the images.

[Css not showing/working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKT3P.png)
[css working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8NXj.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

in theory you should include it in this way in the plugin code

plugins_url() get automatically the address of the plugins folder

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo plugins_url('shortcode-001/style2.css'); ?>">
```

I'm assuming that the shortcode is in a folder inside the plugins folder

Comment: still facing the similar issue